# How to check whether the alertBox is empty or not after clicking ok button?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to get entered values from an Android `AlertBox`.

If `AlertBox` is empty, what would it return?
How would I prevent `AlertBox` from accepting the empty values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580606/null-validation-on-edittext-box-in-alert-dialog-android

Comment: Have a look at this thread, I think it's a similar thing!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785571/alertdialog-how-can-i-run-checks-when-user-hits-ok

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
private boolean getFormData() {
        final String duration = durationView.getText().toString();
        final String time = timeView.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(duration)) {
             durationView.setError(getString(R.string.error_duration_empty));
            durationView.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(time)) {
             timeView.setError(getString(R.string.error_time_empty));
            timeView.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        activityLog.uuid = duration;
        activityLog.uuid = time;
        return true;
    }
```